# Rails application - using cache to transfer info between controllers. Is this how I should do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a rails app which work without problems in development but I get sporadic bug screens in the production (Heroku) environment.  I believe this may be due to my use of "cache" to transfer information ("read" and "write") between controllers.
For example a "Drill" may have one or more associated "Drill_Interest" (companies invested in the drill), and one or more associated "Resource_Estimations".

From the Drills Controller

```
...
def edit
  Rails.cache.write("drill", @drill)
  load_stake
  load_drill_interests
  load_overriding_royalty_interests
  load_resource_estimations
  set_target_resource
end
...
```

From the Resource Estimations Controller

```
...
def new
  @drill = Rails.cache.read("drill")
  @resource_estimations = ResourceEstimation.new
  @resource_estimations.drill_id = @drill.id
end
```

...

A similar example is when adding a company_listing for a company

this is from the Heroku log

```
2014-04-02T03:31:07.413843+00:00 app[web.2]: NoMethodError (undefined method `company_listings' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Company:0x007f80d9004c20>):
2014-04-02T03:31:07.413843+00:00 app[web.2]:   app/controllers/company_listings_controller.rb:17:in `update_multiple'
2014-04-02T03:31:07.413843+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2014-04-02T03:31:07.413843+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2014-04-02T03:31:07.413843+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2014-04-02T03:31:07.413843+00:00 app[web.2]: NoMethodError (undefined method `company_listings' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Company:0x007f80d9004c20>):
2014-04-02T03:31:07.413843+00:00 app[web.2]:   app/controllers/company_listings_controller.rb:17:in `update_multiple'
2014-04-02T03:31:07.413843+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2014-04-02T03:31:07.413843+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2014-04-02T03:31:07.415313+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST   path=/company_listings/update_multiple host=quiet-fortress-3338.herokuapp.com request_id=15fb9890-e31e-4c69-bd1d-cadac8da4abe fwd="203.45.50.22" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=450ms status=500 bytes=873
```

I got this error after 11 attmepts.  On the first 10 I was able to successfully add  company and company_listing rows.  On the 11th and repeating what I had done before I got this error.

This is the rror I get from Heroku

### We're sorry, but something went wrong.

in the routes I have

```
...
resources :drill do
    member do
       match 'p_value_selected', via: [:get,:post]
   end
end

resources :resource_estimations, only: [:new, :create, :destroy] do
    collection do
      get 'edit_multiple'
      post 'update_multiple'
    end
end
....
```

so I should change this to something like ?

```
....
resources :drill do
    member do
        match 'p_value_selected', via: [:get,:post]
        resources :resource_estimations, only: [:new, :create, :destroy] do
            collection do
                get 'edit_multiple'
                post 'update_multiple'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

and how would I reference the drill_id in the resource_Estimations controller ?

thanks in advance and post as as answer so I can accept it - Pierre

Comment: What are the bug you recieve on screen?

Comment: Hi sonnyhe2002.  1- Added some more to query above which I am still investigating 2- In general is my approach, using cach read/write between to communicate between controllers ok ?

Comment: In general, I would not use caching to store complex objects like activerecord objects, because when it is stored, it is converted to string, at least I know memcached and redis will. Secondly cache is usually stored in RAM therefore it is fast, but it is volatile. So it is not good to store persistent data with cache. Lastly, the cache is like global variables, you have to be careful with naming the keys, or it might overwrite better keys (especially with multiple users).

Comment: Hi sonnyhe2002, - if Drills have many Drill_Estimations in the Drill_Estimations controller how do I refer to the Drill (e.g. Drill_id) that the Resource_Estimation ? Could you post as an answer so I can accept it / TIA - Pierre

Comment: If you are in the Drill_Estimations controller and you want to access drill_id, The best way is to use nested routes.

Comment: When I am updating Resource_Estimations I do so in Resource_Estimations controller.  I have posted routes above.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the drill object like this:

```
def create
  @drill = Drill.find params[:drill_id]
  @resource_estimations = ResourceEstimation.create params[:resource_estimation]
  @drill.resource_estimations << @resource_estimation
end
```